# Random hue for text color not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have a function that runs infinitely. It gets a random hue, and then inserts it into the color property. Here is my code:

```
<script>    
  function colorMe(){
    var hue = Math.floor((Math.random() * 359) + 1);
    document.getElementById("hie").style.color = hsl(hue, 75%, 50%);
    colorMe();
  }
  colorMe();
</script>
<p id="hie">I don't know what color this will be!</p>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use setTimeout() to limit the frame rate for your endless running script. Refreshing e.g. every 16ms is fine enough to still have 60 FPS

Comment: Do you make sure your colorMe function is run after the paragraph element exists?  Use an onload event or a delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the `hsl` part in quotes.

```
document.getElementById("hie").style.color = "hsl("+hue+", 75%, 50%)";
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things - first, you're calling `colorMe` from within the `colorMe` function.  You probably don't want to do that.  Second is that `hsl` doesn't exist as a javascript method - it's a css function.  Try setting the color equal to a string which contains your updated hsl color, as seen here:  http://jsfiddle.net/99h5s0L6/

```
function colorMe() {
    var hue = Math.floor((Math.random() * 359) + 1);
    document.getElementById("hie").style.color = "hsl(" + hue + ", 75%, 50%)";
}
colorMe();
```

Comment: [Error] TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("hie").style')
 colorMe (otherApps.html, line 20)
 global code (otherApps.html, line 22)

Comment: do you still have the element with that id on your page?  did you follow the link to the jsfiddle?  it's definitely working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but personally I would use `filter: hue-rotate(30deg)` instead.

I'm not sure about IE support, but it's supported in FF and Chrome (via vendor prefix). Example:

```
-webkit-filter: hue-rotate(30deg);
filter: hue-rotate(30deg);
```

Just vary the degrees of rotation randomly and set it accordingly.

Edit:

Using jQuery:

```
$('#hie').css("-webkit-filter","hue-rotate(" + hue + "deg)")
$('#hie').css("filter","hue-rotate(" + hue + "deg)")
```

Comment: Where would this go in the code? I assume in a <style> tag but would this be the only thing in there or what?

Comment: See edit. I use jQuery to make it easier. Matt's answer seems to work better than mine though.